# Extjs, delete button

Tags: extjs

in this example : http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/progress-bar-pager.html if i want to put an delete button, after the row is deleted from grid, how can i change or delete this record from myData? Because when i change the page, or click o refresh button my row/row's deleted appear again. is there a solution to change the data?

many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
var grid = ...; // Your grid.

var button = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Delete row',
    handler: function() {
        var record = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected();

        if (record !== undefined) {
            grid.store.remove(record);
        }
    }
});
```

If you wish your data to be deleted for real, the grid should use a remote store that loads and removes data from an actual data store. The following means local changes only:

```
proxy: new Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy(myData),
```

you could try removing that and put

```
url: 'http://localhost/path/to/get/data'
```

Refer to the documentation for more info: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store

Comment: your idea its good, but i want to work with cash and i don't want to reload the database each times i delete a product. I have also a function that on click delete the row from my database but i don't want to reload the database. If you have 10-20 product its OK, but if you have 10.000...

Comment: @cosy a delete shouldn't (or, at least, needn't) cause a requery. If you make the assumption that the delete's worked, or restore the deleted record if the delete fails then @Kai's should be fine.

Comment: You can always put a Save-button that will send an AJAX request via `Ext.Ajax.request()` or by doing it via `store.save()`. Just make sure you set `autoSave` to `false` for the store or it will automatically save changes.

Comment: i found the solution using this myData.splice (1,1);

Answer (score 1):

If you look through the source of that example, it is loading the data from an array that is hard-coded:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

        var myData = [
                ['3m Co',71.72,0.02,0.03,'9/1 12:00am'],
                ['Alcoa Inc',29.01,0.42,1.47,'9/1 12:00am'],
                ['Altria Group Inc',83.81,0.28,0.34,'9/1 12:00am'],
                // ...
                ['Verizon Communications',35.57,0.39,1.11,'9/1 12:00am'],
                ['Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.',45.45,0.73,1.63,'9/1 12:00am']
        ];
```

`myData` is re-created from that static definition each time the page loads, so that's why changes do not persist between refreshes.

You need to write two server-side scripts (e.g. PHP scripts). One outputs data of non-deleted records in JSON or XML format. The other deletes record(s) from the database by ID.

Here is a tutorial that covers writing the "getter" PHP script and corresponding Ext JS code for displaying a grid of data on technology products: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/EXT-JS-Passing-Live-Data/. This only covers the first script (the one to retrieve data from the database and output it in JSON format), but it should get you going. Look into overriding the [`remove`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Store.html#event-Ext.data.Store-remove) callback of the store with a function that issues an AJAX request to the second script (the one that deletes record(s) from the database by ID).

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution myData.splice (1,1);